# Avoid overflowing of boxes to box below

Tags: html, css

In the given HTML markup below the middle row pink boxes overflow to the gray box below it. How can I make it certain that the gray box always remain blow the pink boxes. Also here is the link to the html page: http://pastehtml.com/view/axc3iain8.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page 3</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                width: 1000px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }

            #header {
                height: 200px;
                margin: 2px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
                font-size: XX-large;
                background: gray;
            }

            .snip_list {
                min-height: 100px;
                margin: 25px auto;
            }

            .snippet {
                width: 323px;
                float: left;
                margin: 5px;
                font-size: small;
                background: lightpink;
                display: inline;
            }

            #para_middle {
                margin-top: 10px;
                background: gray;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
        </div>

        <div class="snip_list">
            <div class="snippet">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
            </div>

            <div class="snippet">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
            </div>

            <div class="snippet">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="para_middle" class="para">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
                pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="snip_list">
            <div class="snippet">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
            </div>

            <div class="snippet">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
            </div>

            <div class="snippet">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also tried removing "display: inline;" from .snippet but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give

```
overflow:hidden
```

to div.snip-list. It should keep in place the container mantaining the margins.

Comment: I am confused whether I should use overflow:hidden in div.snip-list or clear:both in #para_middle Why should I prefer one to another?

Comment: personally I prefer using overflow:hidden when possible (i.e. if I don't need overflow items appearing) instead of clear:both, because it does not change anything in div-positioning.As an example I could need later the div to float around or so on.

Comment: In the current scenario I can see whole text with overflow:hidden and nothing is is hidden which is not by definition of overflow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow

Comment: You are placing float elements into a div.If not otherwise specified,the browser will create the container div with 0 height, later create the children elements,but finding float elements, simply ignores them,placing the float elements outside and leaving it 0 height.By assigning overflow:hidden you force the browser to recalculate the metrics of the container, that does not ignore anymore the floating element. So actually the container adjustes its size to the children floating element. That's it. There are many solutions to this problem, but the cleanest is trimming overflow, by my opinion.

Comment: Thats really the explanation I was looking for. And this is not found in any of CSS references. If you have links to any more such things please share.

Comment: And What you said is verifiable using Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Simple add the following to `.snip_list`

`clear:both;`

I've coded it up for you here - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/EPzWE/

Comment: Thanks I got to know about jsfiddle. But I think you mistakenly mentioned .snip_list while correct answer will be adding it to #para.

Answer (score 1):

adding a `clear:both` to the `#para_middle` will fix this issue.  Clear will ensure that elements do not overlap on floated elements.  Clear left will ensure that the left edge is clear of floated elements.  Clear right will check right, and clear both will check both left and right.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `snippet`s are floating, hence they're outside the normal flow. You need to make the subsequent elements `clear`. A nice way to achieve this is by adding an invisible clearing block after the ambient element using CSS:

```
.snip_list:after { content: "."; visibility: hidden; display: block; clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 0):

add `<br clear="left" />` after each "row"

or:

```
.fix {
    clear:left;
    height:1px;
    margin:-1px 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

<div class="fix"></div>
```

Comment: This is a reasonable way to do it, but also adds a lot of extra and uneccessary markup.  It'd be good on a case by case basis but there are larger elements that are easier to target